# Can ffmpeg be used to reduce encoded file size back to original after OBS+VLC workflow?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

Wondering if ffmpeg could help me reduce the size of the resulting file called "OBS_VLC_replay.mp4" which is produced as a result of using VLC to playback a video at x1.3 speed (with audio pitch correction to retain x1.0 playback speed audio pitch) of "original_video.mp4", and OBS (OpenBroadcase Studio) used to capture the desktop and speaker-output.

Note that the frame-size/resolution of "original.mp4" and "OBS_VLC_replay.mp4" is same i.e. full-HD @1920x1080, although frame-rate of "original.mp4" is 25fps, and that of "OBS_VLC_replay.mp4" is 30fps. The audio stream in "original.mp4" is aac, recorded @48kHz, while reencoded one by OBS is @44.1kHz. However, the **file size** of "OBS_VLC_replay.mp4" is **significantly larger** (order-of-magnitude), than "original.mp4". I think, it is the video stream's encoding (and extra frames due to higher framerate) that is to blame.

The "original_video.mp4" is produced using Kdenlive and then trimmed using ffmpeg. 
`ffprobe` on "original_video.mp4" says:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
  Duration: 00:03:48.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 316 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 127 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 182 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

`ffprobe` on "OBS_VLC_replay.mp4" says:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.84.100
  Duration: 00:12:14.47, start: 0.067000, bitrate: 2657 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2499 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 145 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

**So question is, can I use ffmpeg on "OBS_VLC_replay.mp4" to get back to 25fps and similar level/type of encoding to bring back the resulting mp4 filesize in close proximity to the "original.mp4" ?**

Comment: This is very inefficient workflow, just use ffmpeg with rubberband filter.

Comment: Thanks again. Indeed, this workflow is terribly inefficient, but recompiling ffmpeg with rubberband filter support was going to be a lot more time-consuming. So, I just trimmed the initial 1 second, and the trailing 1 second of the "OBS_VLC_replay.mp4", using ffmpeg, and it's file size dropped significantly (5% lesser than "original.mp4") !